# Multiple defers vs deferred anonymous function

Tags: go, resource-cleanup

Is it safer or more idiomatic to issue multiple `defer` statements which are dependent on the order, or to defer an anonymous function which packages the logic?

Examples:

```go
defer os.Remove(tempFile.Name())
defer tempFile.Close()
```

In the case above the syntax is minimal, yet the order of defers is reverse to the logic to be executed.

In the case below there are more lines, more "syntax", but the logic is in a more natural order:

```go
defer func() {
    tempFile.Close()
    os.Remove(tempFile.Name())
}()
```

Which one to use?

Comment: Just a small note (not worth a full answer) that `defer` has a performance cost. It's extremely tiny (~75 ns according to my tests on go1.5.1 linux/amd64) and probably not worth considering, but it still should be noted.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

In this example, the anonymous function is easier to read, especially once you add in error handling.

```
f, err := ioutil.TempFile("", "prefix")
if err != nil {
  log.Println("creating temp file:", err)
  return
}
defer func() {
  err := f.Close()
  if err != nil {
    log.Println("close:", err)
  }
  err = os.Remove(f.Name())
  if err != nil {
    log.Println("remove:", err)
  }
}()
```

If you have multiple resources, then multiple `defer`s is generally appropriate.

Answer (score 17):

As [Ross Light](https://stackoverflow.com/users/111866/ross-light) answer [states](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32541870/6309):

> If you have multiple resources, then multiple defers is generally appropriate.

April 2019: But in that case, consider Go 1.13 (Q4 2019), as it does integrate a fix for [go issue 14939: "runtime: defer is slow"](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/14939) and [go issue 6980: "cmd/compile: allocate some defers in stack frames"](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/6980)

See [Go CL 171758: "cmd/compile,runtime: allocate defer records on the stack"](https://go-review.googlesource.com/c/go/+/171758/)

> When a defer is executed at most once in a function body,
> we can allocate the defer record for it on the stack instead
> of on the heap.
>
> This should make defers like this (which are very common) faster.
>
> This optimization applies to 363 out of the 370 static defer sites
> in the cmd/go binary.
>
> ```
> name     old time/op  new time/op  delta
> Defer-4  52.2ns ± 5%  36.2ns ± 3%  -30.70%  (p=0.000 n=10+10)
> ```

---

Oct. 2019 (Go 1.13 is released a few weeks ago)

This [is confirmed (Brad Fitzpatrick)](https://twitter.com/bradfitz/status/1184547163235184640) with [CL 190098](https://go-review.googlesource.com/c/go/+/190098):

> Cost of defer statement  [ `go test -run NONE -bench BenchmarkDefer$ runtime` ]
>
> ```
> With normal (stack-allocated) defers only:         35.4  ns/op
> With open-coded defers:                             5.6  ns/op
> Cost of function call alone (remove defer keyword): 4.4  ns/op
> ```

But [Damien Grisky adds](https://twitter.com/dgryski/status/1184568632082227200):

> Defer gets cheaper, but panic/recover is more expensive.
>
> ```
> Cost of defer: 34ns -> 6ns.
> Cost of panic/recover: 62ns -> 255ns
> ```

That is not a bad trade-off.

---

In other words, while using multiple defer can be idiomatic, that practice was held back by performance costs which are no longer a concern with Go 1.13+.
(as illustrated by [Paschalis](https://tpaschalis.github.io/about/)'s blog post "[What is a defer? And how many can you run?](https://tpaschalis.github.io/defer-internals/)")

That makes [practical use if defer](https://golangbot.com/defer/#practicaluseofdefer) (in places where a function call should be executed irrespective of the code flow) possible.

[John Refior](https://twitter.com/jrefior) notes, however, that [`defer` is synchronous](https://johnrefior.com/gobits/read?post=15):

> Actually defer is executed immediately before the function exits.
> And it occurs synchronously, so the caller waits for defer to complete.

So even if you can now have multiple defer, make sure they are fast, or, as John notes:

> Fortunately it’s easy to wrap a goroutine in a `defer`, giving us the flow control and timing we want, without delaying the caller:
>
> ```golang
> func Handler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
>     log.Println("Entered Handler")
>     defer func() {
>         go func() {
>             time.Sleep(5 * time.Second)
>             log.Println("Exiting goroutine")
>         }()
>         log.Println("Exiting defer")
>     }()
> }
> ```
>
> Often defers are used for locking a mutex, or closing a connection or file descriptor, and the work they do is fast, or we want it to complete before the caller moves on.
>
> But when you’re doing slow work that the client shouldn’t need to wait for at the end of an HTTP handler, making the call asynchronous can substantially improve user experience.

Comment: Can someone shape this into an actual answer to the question, and the bottom-line takeaway? "April 2019: But in that case, consider Go 1.13..." doesn't seem to actually refute the statement "If you have multiple resources, then multiple `defer`s is generally appropriate." It just provides some context on the overheads, right?

Comment: Thanks so much for the clarification, this is a brilliant and complete answer now.